# How to use goog.module to load modules dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library

I want to use goog.module of google closure library to implement JS module lazy loading.

I've been able to use the modules by typing `goog.require(module_name)`. However, the script module will be loaded at the beginning in this way. So I'd like to have the modules loaded dynamically (lazy load) by using goog.module. But I found the documentation for goog.module very hard to understand.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a question, but have you read Closure: The Definitive Guide by Michael Bolin (http://books.google.com/books/about/Closure_The_Definitive_Guide.html?id=p7uyWPcVGZsC)? I got an awesome introduction to the Google Closure Library by reading it, and it talks about modules.

Comment: Wasn't the right place in an answer, and don't have time to summarize the docs, but here's an updated docs link: https://github.com/google/closure-library/wiki/goog.module:-an-ES6-module-like-alternative-to-goog.provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "documentation" I've been able to find for modules, is a mention of the support of modules in Plovr: http://plovr.com/

So the source code of the Plovr library (https://code.google.com/p/plovr/) is the only "documentation" I'm aware of.

Comment: alex23, Plovr does modularization in addition to compilation. See the documentation: http://plovr.com/modules.html So feel free to remove your downvote ;)

Comment: Doh, I was in reddit mode there for a second, where posts starts with 1, not 0, votes :)